# First match in wildcard linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have the below part in my bash script:

```
for file in $(cat $csmtdirpath/$images_to_remove); do mv -v -f /$currentimages/*"$file"* $oldimages >> "$log_image_to_move" 2>> "$log_images_to_move_error"; done
```

This method is using a wildcard which is causing some issues.

So if I have **7AB.115.2** in the $images_to_remove file:

And in the directory where it looks has:

1. 7AB.115.2.1diudniwqndiqnwd
2. 7AB.115.2.2ewfnweofnowenfwef
3. 7AB.115.2.3fewklfkwemfkpwemfpkmw

It also moves the other 3 folders because 7AB.115.2 is a valid option based on *"$file"* wildcard.

How can I make sure that the wildcard only uses the first found match and stops after?

Thanks.

Cheers,

Comment: You probably can't. Use `find  … -exec … -quit` or so.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make sure that the wildcard only uses the first found match and stops after?

To move only the first file found, replace:

```
mv -v -f /$currentimages/*"$file"* $oldimages
```

With:

```
for f in "/$currentimages/"*"$file"*
do
    mv -v -f "$f" "$oldimages"
    break
done
```

`break` causes the loop to exit after the first file.

Also, we have added quotes around the `currentimages` and `oldimages` shell variables to prevent word splitting.